# initialize git on remote harddrive\machine

Tags: git, git-remote

I am trying to initialize my local git on a remote(ethernet connected) hard drive. I have bash installed on my windows machine. so

```
root@DESKTOP-JAMJG6V:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# git config --global user.name "Name"
root@DESKTOP-JAMJG6V:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# git config --global user.email "email@email.email"
root@DESKTOP-JAMJG6V:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# git config --list
user.name=name
user.email=email@email.email
```

Following the instructions at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository where

```
cd /home/user/your_repository
git init
```

I have tried this:

```
root@DESKTOP-JAMJG6V:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# cd "Y:/All Projects/Lab Equipment/DataQ/python/"
bash: cd: Y:/All Projects/Lab Equipment/DataQ/python/: No such file or directory
```

Y is a remote hard drive. What am I doing wrong? The directory I am trying to access exists.

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_: Not reading error message: `Y:/All Projects/Lab Equipment/DataQ/python/: No such file or directory`

Comment: It is possible that the windows 10 Unix bash doesn't support network drives yet since it is a beta version